# Habilitar clic derecho SOLO en un input

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo deshabilitado el clic derecho en toda la página, pero necesito que esté habilitado en un solo input para pegar texto, ya que javascript no permite coger el contenido del portapapeles.

Lo tengo deshabilitado de esta manera:

```
     $(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
        return false;
     });
```

Y trato de habilitar el clic derecho sobre el elemento "#insertlink" (que es un input) o sobre "#pegarlink" (que es un div) de la siguiente manera:

```
  $("#pegarlink").bind("contextmenu", function(e){
        return true;
  });
```

Pero no me funciona, seguramente sea porque la regla anterior es mas estricta, como puedo habilitar el menú derecho sobre un único input?

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el [objetivo](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) del evento que jQuery pasa a la función, y así  determinar el elemento sobre el que ha sido activado el evento.

```
$(document).on('contextmenu',function(e){

    if ( e.target.id == 'pegarlink' ) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
});
```

Otra consideración es que el método [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/#entry-longdesc) se considera obsoleto, se recomienda utilizar [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) en su lugar.

Comment: Muchas gracias me funcionó!